# Erro ao buscar registro com FirstOrDefaultAsync ASP .NET CORE 3.0

Tags: sql-server, angular, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Tenho um método para buscar o cliente no banco de dados pelo numero do CPF(sem pontos, só os numeros), porém no banco de dados o tipo está como VARCHAR.

Fiz alguns testes pelo POSTMAN para testar a rota da API. Quando coloco no método que vou enviar o parametro pelo `SearchCliente([FromBody]string cpf)` e envio o POST com o numero do CPF pelo Body do POSTMAN ele retorna o cliente, mas se eu coloco no método `SearchCliente(string cpf)` e envio o numero do CPF ele retorna NotFound.

Também coloquei uma mensagem para verificar o erro, mas percebi que não está entrando na condição IF.

Abaixo o código completo do método como funciona:

```html
        // GET: api/cliente/search/12345678901
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> SearchCliente([FromBody]string cpf)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.cpf == cpf);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound(new { message = "CPF não cadastrado!" });
            }

            return cliente;
        }
```

E o código do método que não funciona:

```html
        // GET: api/cliente/search/12345678901
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> SearchCliente(string cpf)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.cpf == cpf);

            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound(new { message = "CPF não cadastrado!" });
            }

            return cliente;
        }
```

Abaixo algumas imagens dos testes no POSTMAN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei converter para ToString, mas não resolveu também. Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando?

Desde já agradeço muito!

Código TypeScript que faz o POST:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClienteService } from '../services/cliente.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  router: Router;

  constructor(public service: ClienteService, public http: HttpClient, router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  cpf: string;
  readonly rootURL = "http://localhost:54038/api"

  onSearchCliente(form:NgForm){
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/search', this.cpf).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.router.navigate(['', 'painel-cliente']);
      },
      err =>{
        console.log(err);
        this.router.navigate(['', 'acesso-negado']);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que você pretende passar o CPF na URL ao invés de no _body_?

Comment: Não! Eu estou enviando via POST através daquele input text da imagem acima

Comment: E como está o payload sendo enviado ali? Você pode vê-lo na aba _network_.

Comment: Coloquei a imagem do payload

Answer (score 0):

Veja, você está disparando uma requisição assim:

```js
this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/search', this.cpf)
```

Falta um pedaço da URL:

```js
this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/cliente/search', this.cpf)
```

Comment: Nossa.. nem tinha visto mesmo! Alterei aqui, agora ele deu erro 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: Aí é outro problema. Acredito que seja o caso de abrir outra pergunta, senão essa thread sai do foco.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou ver aqui. Mas obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: Não. era porque estava como [FromBody]... Tirei e continua dando NotFound! Estranho que ele não retorna a mensagem de vazio!

Comment: @RDamazio Não jovem, o `[FromBody]` informa que você irá passar os parâmetros pelo corpo da requisição, se você tirar é óbvio que não vai funcionar.

Comment: Entendi.. Vou ter que pesquisar aqui sobre o erro 415

Comment: Cheque o payload que está indo, deve ter algum header informando o tipo de conteúdo

Comment: Acho que notei uma coisa verificando o payload... Ele está enviando somente o número do CPF sem aspas sem nada. E no POSTMAN quando dava certo eu enviava com aspas duplas e o formato era JSON. Será que é isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107601/discussion-between-linq-and-rdamazio).